# Consider the square defined by $0 \leq Re(z) \leq 1$ and $0 \leq Im(z) \leq1$. Determine ...

Tags: complex-numbers

I have the following problem to solve:

> Consider the square defined by $0 \leq \operatorname{Re}(z) \leq 1$ and $0 \leq \operatorname{Im}(z) \leq1$. Determine the image of this square by the function $f: \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}, f(z)=z+1-i$.

Anyone can help me?

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem?  Do you know all the definitions here (for example, what they mean by the "image")? Have you tried looking at a similar problem in your textbook or notes?

Comment: This is very easy. What have you tried so far? One technique is to find the corners of your square and find where those corners go under the transformation. What figure do those four image points make? How could you describe that figure mathematically?

Comment: It's not me who is trying to solve the problem. A friend of mine is, and I don't really know what he did so far : P

Comment: Then why do you ask this question and not your friend?

Comment: He doesn't speak English, haha.

Answer (score 2):

The function is taking a point in $\mathbb C$ and mapping it ahead one in the real line, and down one in the imaginary line. Thus the bounds were previously 0 to 1 for reals and are now 1 to 2, and the bounds were 0 to 1 for the imaginary numbers, which are now -1 to 0.